# Zeros of functions of the form $\lambda_1e^{x} + ... + \lambda_ne^{nx}$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to know if there is a maximum number of zeros that a function of the form $\lambda_1e^{x} + ... + \lambda_ne^{nx}$ with $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n \in \mathbb{R}, x \in [0,\infty)$ can have. Of all the examples I've cooked up so far I've been able to have at most one real zero, but I don't know if this is true in general.

Comment: You can have up to $n$ roots by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Answer (score 2):

It can have $n-1$ real zeros just take a look at
$$e^{x}(e^{x} -1) (e^{x} -2) \cdots (e^{x} -(n-1)).$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $p(x) = \lambda_1 x + \dots + \lambda_n x^n$. Then your function is $f(x) = p(e^x)$. The function $f$ has $k$ zeroes iff $p$ has $k$ positive zeroes so it is clear that $f$ has at most $n - 1$ zeroes and by choosing $p$ appropriately we can make $f$ have exactly $n - 1$ zeroes. For a concrete example, take

$$ p = x(x-1) \dots (x - (n - 1)). $$

Answer (score 1):

You can write
$$\lambda_1 e^x+\cdots+\lambda_n e^{nx}=\lambda_1 t+\cdots+\lambda_n t^n$$
where we put $t=e^x$.
The number of real solutions of your equation is the number of positive solutions of the equation $\lambda_n t^n+\cdots+\lambda_1t=0$, equivalently the
number of positive solutions of the equation $\lambda_n t^{n-1}+\cdots+\lambda_1=0$.